# Unexplained PHP/MySQL error. Code works on my test server, but not the permanent server

Tags: php, mysql

http://zeel.dyndns.org/ss/home/

This is the homepage for my site on my test server, it works great. So do all the other pages. However on my permanent remote server (justhost)

http://cvca.ohiofbla.org/store/home/

I get:

> Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied
>   argument is not a valid MySQL result
>   resource in
>   /home/ohiofbl1/public_html/schools/cvca/store/home/index.php
>   on line 43

I don't see any problems in the code, and the same code works fine on the testing server.
The only difference is that I have an included file that defines variables for SQL  user/pass/dbname that are different depending on the server. But the only file that is different is that include file.

Am I missing something?

```
<?php session_start(); require("../includes/config.php");?>
<?php $title = "Home"; ////////////////////////////////////////////?>
<?php require("../includes/head.php");
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////?>
<?php
$con = mysql_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass);
if (!$con)
{
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}?>

<div id="index_structure">
<div id="index_left">
<div id="index_top">
<h2>Welcome to the CVCA School Store! </h2>
<p>Here you can purchase items from the school store, and then pick them 
   up from school the next day. </p>
</div>

<div id="index_bottom">
<p align="center"><img src="../images/School Store 014.png" width="30%" />&nbsp;
<img src="../images/School Store 015.png" width="30%" />&nbsp;
<img src="../images/School Store 016.png" width="30%" /></p><br />
<p><strong>Hours:</strong> Mon - Fri, 7:45 - 8:05 AM. On school days. </p>
<p><strong>Location:</strong> Corner of west cafe </p>
<p>Backpack sales start in May - August for all new 7th graders. 
   Supplies are available year round.</p>
<p>Empty shoeboxes are accepted for Operation Shoebox at all times. </p>
<p>We are always looking for parent helpers and student employees. </p>
<p>School uniforms are available for fitting purposes. 
   Uniforms are available for purchase at 
<span class="bluelink"><a href="http://cvcastore.com/">cvcastore.com</a>
</span></p>
<p><img src="../images/shirts.png" width="32%" /></p></div></div>
<div id="index_sidebar">
<h3 align="left">Featured items:</h3><hr />

<?php
function random_one($dbname, $con) 
{ 
  mysql_select_db($dbname, $con);
  unset($result);
  unset($col);
  $i = 1;
  while($i = 1) 
  { 
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM items\n"."ORDER BY RAND()\n"."LIMIT 1");
    $col = mysql_fetch_array($result); //This is line 43 from the error
    if (file_exists("../" . $col['ImagePath']) == true)
    {
      echo "<h4><a href='../item/?item=" . $col['ItemNumber'] . "'>" .
           $col['ItemName'] . "</h4><br />
           <img src='../" . $col['ImagePath'] . "' border='0' /></a>";
      break;
    }
  }
  ?><hr /><?php
}  
random_one($dbname, $con);
random_one($dbname, $con);
random_one($dbname, $con);

?></div></div>    

<?php require("../includes/foot.php"); ///////////////////////////////?>
```

Comment: Another example of insufficient error checking.

Comment: try changing line 42 to `$result = mysql_query(...) or die(mysql_error());` to see what's wrong with your query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem myself.

```
"SELECT * FROM items\n"."ORDER BY RAND()\n"."LIMIT 1"
```

The table "items" is actually "Items", but my Windows-based test server ignored that difference. The permanent server is Linux-based however, and it saw "i" and got lost. I changed the names and everything works fine.

Comment: There are several good pieces of trouble shooting among the answers.  Just trying out SQL strings stripped for simplicity (SELECT field FROM items") would have been a good start.

Comment: Interesting. Due to issues like these I have developed a habit of always writing my code imagining everything is case sensitive even if it is not. You may call that paranoid, but helps me avoid lot of trouble.

Comment: @rineez Not paranoid at all, things that aren't case sensitive are the weird ones. Someone has to go to the effort of writing a system that allows for that behavior, so it's better to assume they *didn't*. In this case the lower case `i` was a typo, but Windows let it pass without error. I probably could have fixed it far faster had it thrown an error the *first* time.

Answer (score 2):

Well nothing is wrong with the query string I checked it myself (although I agree with rineez, there is no reason for those \n). The problem might be either with the variable $dbname, or more likely the while loop itself. It is an infinte loop that will not exit, since you haven't done anything to the $i variable for it to change thus exiting the while loop.

Answer (score 1):

You should always check if any rows are returned prior to iterating.

Run the query against your production DB directly, via terminal, or GUI (like PHPMyAdmin, SQLYog, etc.) and see what record(s), if any, are returned.

Answer (score 1):

Try echoing the variable $dbname and verify it has correct value.
I think just host will add your cpanel username as prefix when you create a database name...

...and I wonder why you have to use \n and concatenations to form your query string.

Comment: I'm in the process of learning PHP, and MySQL. I probably copied that from an example somewhere and modified it to my needs.